# Omnigraffle - how to make double ended arrows?

Tags: macos, omnigraffle

I'm learning Omnigraffle and am ok with most shapes. But I want arrows with heads at each end, like this (done in Pages.app):

[image]

I'd also like to know how to put the tips of the arrows where I want, rather than Omnigraffle's default which is to attach a line to a corner:, like this:

[image]

Following Dave Delong's answer below, I realized that you have to style each end of the line.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Maybe http://forums.omnigroup.com/forumdisplay.php?f=4 is the better place for this?

Comment: Thanks Patrix. I just keep thinking of coming here these days. I find I get better answers, faster, and that includes the developer forums on Apple, and specific product forums. However, if I'm supposed to go to the latter, perhaps the moderators will advise me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select the line (or lines) in your OmniGraffle document
2. Open the Style Inspector (Inspectors Menu ▸ Styles, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>)
3. Select the second style inspector ("Lines and Shapes")

   [image: Lines and Shapes Inspector]
4. Use the popup menus to choose an arrow style

   [image: Arrow styles]

Comment: Thanks Dave, I found this but didn't realize you had to style each end of the line separately. I've updated my question to refer this, but thanks a ton for solving it..